# How can I display the player's balance in tablist plugin on a Minecraft Paper Server?

Tags: plugins, server, minecraft

I am about to create a Minecraft Paper Server (1.19.4), on which every player has a balance for their own, powered by the Minecraft "EssentialsX" Plugin from [EssentialsX](https://essentialsx.net/downloads.html).

It is possible to call the balance of a player via /balance, as I know.
I wonder if it is possible to display the current amount money individually in the "TAB" Plugin [TAB](https://modrinth.com/plugin/tab-was-taken/version/3.3.2), like the Ping for each player using %ping%.

I tried to find a similar accessible value like %ping%, which could fit for the individual players itself, something like "%player_balance%" (which is not working).

As far as I have seen, there is a Placeholder API for the TAB Plugin, but I did not find any related content to the player's balance.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome on STackOverflow. This website is made for programming, so your question is off-topic. But. Firstly, don't use modrinth website, mostly when it's available for free [here](https://github.com/NEZNAMY/TAB/releases). Then, you should simply use PlaceholderAPI placeholders and as explained [here](https://www.spigotmc.org/threads/essentials-balance-placeholder.447398/) you need to use Vault then do `/papi ecloud download vault)` for PAPI placeholders support of vault, and finally use `%vault_eco_balance_fixed%`

Comment: Thank you very much for your help @Elikill58 , I am glad it works as I expected!